# Can I pass information from componentDidCatch to getDerivedStateFromError?

Tags: reactjs

The `componentDidCatch` function is called with an info object that isn't provided to `getDerivedStateFromError`. I'd like to provide my users with more detailed information about the error, so that they can more easily communicate it to me.

I can log an error on the server from `componentDidCatch`, but ideally I'd like to generate an error ID so that I can quickly find the specific error that the user sees. But I see no way to share state between `componentDidCatch` and the render method to show that ID to the user. I have tried setting the `state` in `getDerivedStateFromError`, but that's not the `state` used in `componentDidCatch`.

I could dump it to the console but I'd rather make it easier on the user.

Comment: Maybe use `setState` in the `componentDidCatch`?

Comment: Hmm... that does seem to work, as long as I disabled `getDerivedStateFromError`. I would have thought that `getDerivedStateFromError` was meant to be the only state-altering entity, but it seems to be redundant with the ability of `componentDidCatch` to set state.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion of @Emile Bergeron, the key I was lacking is that `componentDidCatch` is permitted to mutate the state. The documentation implies that this is the job of `getDerivedStateFromError`, but they're overlapping mechanisms.

So the following code solves the problem:

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    const errorId = uuid();
    this.setState({error, info, errorId});
    logErrorToMyService(error, info, errorId);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.error) {
      // Even more debugging info can be provided with 
      // error and info, but now the id is in my logs.
      return <h1>Error id {this.state.errorId}</h1>;
    }

    return this.props.children; 
  }
}
```